# How to create the file check session Login on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, session

I wanna ask the checking session login in PHP language. I mean:

On basic, After user login on the website, I will start the sesssion:

```
$_session['memberName'] = $member['Firstname'];
```

**Note**: $member is an array that query from the DB. Firstname is a column in DB.

when I don't want user access to the profile.php page without LOGIN. I will set the condition in profile.php file is:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['memberName'] == "")
{
redirectMsg('You must login to access this page','login.php');
}
```

**Note**: redirectMsg() is the function that I have written for using Javascript to announce the message and redirect to some page.

That way is too difficult to control. That mean I have to add that code for each page I want to...when I change something about that, that will take more time...

Now I want to have a file to control that session, I can change the value but it will not take time...How can I do that...please direct the way for me...OR

Have anybody have other solutions to solve, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a login page authentication with sessions in php.try this code.

LoginForm.php:

```
<form action="LoginCheck.php"  method="POST">
        <h1 align="left" style="color:red">LoginForm</h1>
        <table align="left" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>UserName:</td><td> <input type="text" name="username"></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password" ></td> </tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="register.php"  style="color:red">New User Register Here.</a></td></tr>
        </table>
      </form>
```

Session_start.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']))
{
header('Location: index.php');
}


?>
```

LoginCheck.php:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysql!");
        mysql_select_db("crud",$con);
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];

        $result=mysql_query("select * from user_register where user_name='$username' and emp_password='$password'");
        echo mysql_num_rows($result);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result))
        {
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['username'];
        header("location: emp_details.php");
        }
        else
        {
        header("location: index.php");
        } 
    ?>
```

session_logout.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['uname']);
    header("Location:loginform.php");
?>
```

I think this is useful to you.

Comment: That's useful but I did at the same on you.

Comment: My asking is: If I have the profile.php page but I don't want the user click on the history link to access page WITHOUT login. I will check the session and I have to do that for the many files like that. It takes more time. I want to have a file or something to add or change the checked conđition faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['memberName']))
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('You must login to access this page','login.php'');</script>
<?php
   header("location:login.php");
}
```

Use the above code , which will check for user session and login status. If user is not loged in, the user will alerted by javascirpt alert message and then will be redirected to login page.

Comment: Please always add an explanation paragraph to your answer / code. It is best practice to explain your answer.